# How to replace % with html tag in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following code in PHP:

```
$fullString = "a %sample% word go %here%";
```

And I want to replace % with html tag (`<span style='color:red'> and </span>`). This is what I want after replacing:

```
$fullString ="a <span style='color:red'>sample</span> word go <span style='color:red'>here</span>";
```

What should I do to accomplish this result using PHP function like `str_replace, preg_replace` etc.?
Thanks.

Comment: Something like this? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/aVk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do....

```
$string = "a %sample% word go %here%";
echo preg_replace('~%(.*?)%~', '<span style="color:red">$1</span>', $string);
```

That says replace everything between the first % and next occurring % sign with the spans. The `()` groups everything inside those percents into the $1.

Output:

```
a <span style="color:red">sample</span> word go <span style="color:red">here</span>
```